# how to parse a .RC file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, pegjs

I am trying to parse the data from a .RC (resource definition file) to JSON using js with simple fs.readFile function, however I am getting SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token. At the moment I've found no other solution to parse this type of file, pls provide me with inputs to do so. Below is .RC example.

```
#include "shapes.h"

ShapesCursor CURSOR SHAPES.CUR
ShapesIcon ICON SHAPES.ICO

ShapesMenu MENU
{
  POPUP "&Shape"
  {
    MENUITEM "&Clear", ID_CLEAR
    MENUITEM "&Rectangle", ID_RECT
  }
}
```

I found a package in node called, 'Jison' which is an API for creating parsers in JavaScript similar to 'PegJS', however I couldn't figure out the grammer that needs to be written for my file type also if it would support the file type. The parsed structure could look similar to,

```
{
    "directive": [
        "include",
        "shapes.h"
    ],
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "ShapesCursor",
            "values": [
                "CURSOR",
                "SHAPES.CUR"
            ],
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "name": "ShapesIcon",
            "values": [
                "CURSOR",
                "SHAPES.ICO"
            ],
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "name": "POPUP",
            "values": [
                "&Shape"
            ],
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "MENUITEM",
                    "values": [
                        "&Clear",
                        "ID_CLEAR"
                    ],
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "MENUITEM",
                    "values": [
                        "&Rectangle",
                        "ID_RECT"
                    ],
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: [JSON](http://www.json.org/) is a well defined format (check the [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)), I am not sure a JS parser exists for such files.

Have you an example implementation from another language? Please gather more details and [edit] your question.

Comment: I found a package in node called, 'Jison' which is an API for creating parsers in JavaScript similar to 'PegJS', however I couldn't figure out the grammer that needs to be written for my file type also if it would support the file type.

Comment: Writing your own parser can be a huge task if you want to cover a library and its edge cases. Perhaps provide some links to the resource file doc.

Comment: How would you like it to be represented with JSON?

Comment: @FelixMosheev, hi I updated in the question.

Comment: You will need to build the language of  the RC file. PegJs is good tool for that. just redo their calculator tutorial, it helped me :]

Answer (score 1):

Below grammar can be used for parsing Resource Description files to a JSON.

```
{
    var word_Obj = {};
    var word_alnum_Obj = {};
    var word_alnumsp_Obj = {};
    var dir_Obj = {};
    var valStateDec_Obj = {};
    var stateName_Obj = {};
    var valStateVal_Obj = {};
    var word_Count = 0;
    var word_alnum_Count = 0;
    var word_alnumsp_Count = 0;
    var dir_Count = -1;
    var valStateDec_Count = 0;
    var stateName_Count = -1;
    var valStateVal_Count = -1;
    var begin_Count = -1;
    var end_Count = -1;
    var child_Count = -1;
    var children_Count = -1;
    var flag = 0;
}
Expected = dir:directive * nl * states:state nl* Ending:EOL {if (begin_Count === end_Count) { return { Parsed_RC: { Directive_Obj: dir, States_Obj: states, ENDING: Ending } } } else { return "Incorrect .RC file" } }
directive = "#" d: word space* v:word_alnumsp nl+ { dir_Count++; dir_Obj = { ['Directive_' + dir_Count]: { "Dir": d, "_text": v } }; return dir_Obj;}
state = (valState looping)*
    looping = (loopStart loopEnd*)*
        loopStart = beg child: valState + { begin_Count++; children_Count++; child_Count++; return {['loopStart_' + begin_Count]: begin_Count, ['child_' + children_Count]: child } }
loopEnd = end {end_Count++; child_Count--; return { ['loopEnd_' + end_Count]: end_Count }; }
valState = stateName(valStateVal) * nl +
    //valStateDec = space+ decState_val:word_alnumsp {valStateDec_Count++; valStateDec_Obj = {['ValStateDec_Obj'+valStateDec_Count]:decState_val}; return valStateDec_Obj;}
    stateName = space * state_name:word_alnumsp {if (state_name === 'BEGIN') { begin_Count++; children_Count++; child_Count++; return { ['loopStart_' + begin_Count]: begin_Count } } if (state_name === 'END') { end_Count++; child_Count--; return { ['loopEnd_' + end_Count]: end_Count }; } if (child_Count < 0) { flag = 1; } stateName_Count++; stateName_Obj = { ['StateName_Obj' + stateName_Count]: state_name }; return stateName_Obj; }
valStateVal = space + valState_val:(word_alnumsp comma?)* { valStateVal_Count++; valStateVal_Obj = { ['_attributes_Obj' + valStateVal_Count]: valState_val }; return valStateVal_Obj}
word = wo:letter + { return wo.join("") }
word_alnum = al:alnum + { return al.join("") }
word_alnumsp = alsp:alnumsp + { return alsp.join("") }

beg = space * ([{]) space* nl +
    end = space * ([}]) space* nl +
        comma = space * [,] space* { return ","}

letter = [a - zA - Z]
alnum = [a - zA - Z0 - 9]
alnumsp = [a - zA - Z0 - 9"'&._()\\|+:]
    space = " "
    nl = '\n' {valStateVal_Count = -1; return "NL"}
    EOL = !. {return "EOF"}
```